# How to create signed extrinsic in outer node?

Tags: extrinsic, substrate-node, transaction-pool

What is idiomatic way to submit signed extrinsic in outer node?

Is it using `BasicPool` and [`submit_local`](https://docs.rs/sc-transaction-pool-api/21.0.0/sc_transaction_pool_api/trait.LocalTransactionPool.html#tymethod.submit_local)? Would Rust example at the bottom be be good approach? If it is how to:

- properly choose `period` and `current` args for `Era::mortal`?
- obtain `nonce` for `frame_system::CheckNonce`?

Also it seems using [`subxt`](https://github.com/paritytech/subxt) requires way less boilerplate than example below.

Is there better interface, with less boilerplate than in example below, I could use when submitting signed extrinsics in outer node?

There's always possibility of using `subxt` but that doesn't seem right since I've got access to runtime, transaction pool and needed types within outer node.

```
fn submit_signed_extrinsic_example(
    transaction_pool: &dyn sc_transaction_pool_api::LocalTransactionPool<
        Block = Block,
        Hash = Hash,
        Error = sc_transaction_pool::error::Error,
    >,
    keystore: &sc_keystore::LocalKeystore,
    genesis_hash: sp_core::H256,
    block_hash: sp_core::H256,
) -> Result<()> {
    let call = my_pallet::Call::my_call {};

    let keys = keystore.sr25519_public_keys(key_types::ACCOUNT);

    let public = keys.first().ok_or(Error::NoNodeAccountKey)?.clone();

    let extra: runtime::SignedExtra = (
        frame_system::CheckNonZeroSender::<runtime::Runtime>::new(),
        frame_system::CheckSpecVersion::<runtime::Runtime>::new(),
        frame_system::CheckTxVersion::<runtime::Runtime>::new(),
        frame_system::CheckGenesis::<runtime::Runtime>::new(),
        frame_system::CheckMortality::<runtime::Runtime>::from(sp_runtime::generic::Era::mortal(
            0, 0,
        )),
        frame_system::CheckNonce::<runtime::Runtime>::from(0),
        frame_system::CheckWeight::<runtime::Runtime>::new(),
        pallet_transaction_payment::ChargeTransactionPayment::<runtime::Runtime>::from(0),
    );

    let payload = runtime::SignedPayload::from_raw(
        call.clone().into(),
        extra.clone(),
        (
            (),
            runtime::VERSION.spec_version,
            runtime::VERSION.transaction_version,
            genesis_hash,
            genesis_hash,
            (),
            (),
            (),
        ),
    );

    let signature = sp_runtime::MultiSignature::Sr25519(payload.using_encoded(|payload| {
        keystore
            .sr25519_sign(key_types::ACCOUNT, &public, payload)?
            .ok_or(Error::NoNodeAccountKey)
    })?);

    let extrinsic = runtime::UncheckedExtrinsic::new_signed(
        call.clone().into(),
        sp_runtime::AccountId32::from(public).into(),
        signature,
        extra,
    );
    let block_id = sp_runtime::generic::BlockId::Hash(block_hash);

    transaction_pool.submit_local(&block_id, extrinsic.into())?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Mmm, I think in this case Subxt isn't super relevant (it's more about interacting with a node via the RPC APIs), though in theory you could build the signed extrinsic bytes with it if having those helped. Probably not worth all of the added dependencies just for that though, even if it was useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question:

If you look at [substrate RPC interface](https://docs.rs/sc-rpc-api/latest/sc_rpc_api/author/trait.AuthorApiServer.html), calls `author_submitExtrinsic` and `author_submitAndWatchExtrinsic` correspond to `submit_one` and `submit_and_watch` of [TransactionPool trait](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sc_transaction_pool_api/trait.TransactionPool.html).

So easiest way to submit extrinsics in outer node is to grab `TransactionPool` and utilize it for extrinsic submission.